# Elastics Search email search mismatch with match query using com

Tags: elasticsearch

```
GET candidates1/candidate/_search
{
  "fields": ["contactInfo.emails.main"], 
  "query": { 
    "bool": { 
      "must": [
        { 
          "match": { 
            "contactInfo.emails.main": "com" 
          }
        }  
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

---

```
GET candidates1/candidate/_search
{
  "size": 5,
  "fields": [
    "contactInfo.emails.main"
  ],
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "contactInfo.emails.main": "com"
    }
  }
}
```

Hi,
When i am using the above query i am getting results like ['nraheem@dbtech1.com','arelysf456@gmai1.com','ron@rgb52.com'] but i am not getting emails like ['pavann.aryasomayajulu@gmail.com','kumar@gmail.com','raj@yahoo.com']

But when i am using the query to match "gmail.com", i am getting results which have gmail.com

So My question is when i am using "com" in the first query, i am expecting results that include gmail.com as "com" is present in gmail.com. But that is not happening

Note: we are having almost 2Million emailid and most of them are gmail.com , yahoo.com or hotmail but only few are of other types.

Answer (score 1):

**"contactInfo.emails.main"** fields seem to be an [analyzed field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/mapping-intro.html#_index_2).

In elasticsearch all string fields are analyed using [Standard Analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) and are converted into tokens.You can see how your text is getting analyzed using [analyze api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html). Email Ids mentioned by you ending in number before `com` are getting analyzed as `nraheem` , `dbtech1` , `com`. Use following query to see the `tokens`.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_analyze' -d '
{
 "analyzer" : "standard",
 "text" : "nraheem@dbtech1.com"
}'
```

As you can see there is a separate term `com` being created. While if you analyze `kumar@gmail.com` you will get `tokens` like `kumar` , `gmail.com`. There is no separate token `com` created in this case.

This is because `Standard Analyzer` splits the terms when it encounters some special characters like `@,?` etc or  **numbers** too. You can create `custom Analyzer` to meet your requirement.

Hope this helps!!